# addFromPromptAsync does not work correctly in Excel Online

Tags: office-js

When using Office.context.document.bindings.addFromPromptAsync() in the desktop version of Excel, the prompt works fine and allows the user to select cells within the sheet to create the range binding.  In Office Online, when the prompt shows up, the user cannot actually select the data.  They have to just type in the range.  Why does this discrepancy occur?  Is this a known bug to the Office team?